# ASHX File Download

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I am working on a project where the user can download a file that is stored in a MemoryStream.

The issue i have is when the user clicks the row in the table to download the particular file, any subsequent clicks anywhere on the page after download this files causes the file to download again.

It looks like the EventTarget on the subsequent requests is still "MyDownloadsPanel"

This is how i download a file

Master Page - PageLoad

```
if (Request.EventTarget() == "MyDownloadsPanel")
{
    Session["FileExportDownload"] = _fileExportSvc.SelectFileExport(int.Parse(Request.EventArgument()), (string)Session["UsersDatabase"]);
    Response.Redirect("FileExportFileHandler/FileExportDownloadFileHandler.ashx");
}
```

Master Page - OnItemDataBound

```
  if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
    FileExport fileExport = (FileExport)item.DataItem;

    FileDownloadStatus fileDownloadStatus = GetStatusText(fileExport);
    if (fileDownloadStatus == FileDownloadStatus.Completed)
        item.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("__doPostBack('MyDownloadsPanel',{0});", fileExport.ID);

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image fileTypeImage = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)item.Cells[0].FindControl("uxFileTypeImage");
    fileTypeImage.ImageUrl = GetDownloadImageFromExtensionPath(fileExport.FileExtension);

    item.Cells[1].Text = ShortenDownloadFilename(fileExport.Filename);

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image fileStatusImage = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)item.Cells[2].FindControl("uxFileStatusImage");
    fileStatusImage.ImageUrl = GetImageUrlOnStatus(fileDownloadStatus);
}
```

FileExportDownloadFileHandler.ashx - ProcessRequest

```
    FileExport fileExport = (FileExport) HttpContext.Current.Session["FileExportDownload"];
HttpContext.Current.Session["FileExportDownload"] = null;

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ContentType = fileExport.MimeType;
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + string.Format("{0}_{1}.{2}",fileExport.Filename, fileExport.DateTimeRequested.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"), fileExport.FileExtension));  //this fixes the filename
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileExport.Data);
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Why are you using Session to pass the file download information? Why not pass via query string, then retrieve the file within the ASHX? That way you can avoid using Session.

Comment: Yeah i can see your point about the sessions i will consider this.

Comment: Could the issue be down to you putting the code in the master page (just a thought) could result in a leaky implementation if the master page is shared with multiple pages.

Comment: Hi @War is there anyway to get around this as this information is required in every page

Comment: Can you include the source from the client side please?

Comment: Your "Download click" shouldn't be handled with server side code.  This can be a lot simpler.  The hyperlink on your page should have a link to your handler with a target of blank: `<a href="FileExportFileHandler/FileExportDownloadFileHandler.ashx" target="_blank">Click me</a>` -- Then in your handler you do not need to clear the response Stream, etc because it will be a separate response and it will not mess with the other functionality on the server side.